# Using web scraped data for consumer price indices

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, academic-graduate

Is there information and literature regarding comparative consumer price index methods? Specifically, the web scraping method of index construction?

Answer (score 2):

[Take a look at Billion Prices Project](http://bpp.mit.edu/):

> The Billion Prices Project is an academic initiative that uses prices
>   collected from hundreds of online retailers around the world on a
>   daily basis to conduct economic research.

Also take a look at [PriceStats](http://www.pricestats.com/)

> PriceStats collects online prices to provide daily inflation updates
>   for 22 economies.

[Overview of the PiceStats approach](http://www.pricestats.com/approach/overview)

More broadly, price index construction is a huge literature full of pitfalls so it is difficult to point you to a generic but also advanced presentation of the issues. But you might start with [Consumer Prices, the Consumer Price Index, and the Cost of Living](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2646934?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (Boskin, Dulberger, Gordon, Griliches and Jorgenson (1998)), a Journal of Economic Perspectives piece on the subject.

Comment: Hi, I am working on a project comparing international uses of web scraping to compile their respective CPI's. Would you happen to have any leads regarding this? Thank you

Comment: Also would you happen to know how to program such web scraping programs to help me test them? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Spanish you can reach IPC Online project in Argentina. https://ipconlinebb.wordpress.com/